# Audio volume stuck at low level and adjusting volume has no effect?

Tags: iphone, audio

When I use my app (on the device), the actual volume works OK for a while, but after a few days it seems to get 'stuck' at a low level. 
Adjusting the volume rocker has no effect - and it shows 'Ringer' text. I've noticed that other people's apps are similarly affected if they show the 'Ringer' text when adjusting the volume. But apps which don't show 'Ringer' text are not affected by this.

How would I remove the 'Ringer' text and get my app to respond properly to different volumes?

Comment: What do you mean 'after a few days'? Your app runs for a few days? What OS version?

Comment: OS 3.0. It just seems to get stuck after a day or so.

Comment: Just a note: i'm not sure which application do that, but on my iPod touch i see the same problem, the only sound application is the native iPod app. When this problem happens, i restart the iPod and it works back!! So are you sure its your app? it might be a bug in the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code on Apple's forums which fixes it. You have to use the AVFoundation.framework and put a bit of code into your app delegate. And put an audio file called 'blank.aif' into your project. Basically, it's a hack which prepares a file to play, but then never plays it. This fools the system into thinking that sound is being played all the time, which allows the user to use the main volume control.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

//...


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

//volume control hack
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"blanksound" ofType:@"aif"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
AVAudioPlayer *volumeHack = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil]retain];
[fileURL release];
[volumeHack prepareToPlay];

// other applicationDidFinishLaunching stuff
}
```